# How to uninstall Ubuntu legacy (needed UEFI)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.10 on my new laptop, alongside the already installed Windows 10, using this site : 
http://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-16-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot/

I came across some problems, since I installed Ubuntu in legacy mode, but it needed to be in UEFI mode... As can be seen in the link above, it told me to mess about with my disk space management and I'm afraid I did something irreversible. Any solutions on how I can delete my legacy ubuntu (without getting rid of windows 10 of course)? Precise detailed steps will be necessary as I'm new to operating systems and linux.

Also, I have difficulty booting the legacy ubuntu recently (finishes booting very rarely). Windows 10 still works fine.

Comment: If install works when booting in BIOS mode, then you can use Boot-Repair or manually uninstall grub2's BIOS boot version and install grub2's UEFI boot version. Be sure to boot Ubuntu installer in UEFI mode & Use advanced mode in Boot-Repair and check uninstall of grub. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info and:
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: 'something irreversible' is a bit vague.  What, exactly, is the problem?

Comment: @oldfred I suppose when you say the BIOS boot version, you mean the legacy Ubuntu? How do I manually uninstall the BIOS boot version?

Comment: Need to see details from Summary report, otherwise may suggest the wrong thing.  But generally you need to use Something Else and choose same / and new /, so you do not modify other partitions. But if gpt partitioned with Windows 10, you do not need full reinstall, just reinstall of grub which Boot-Repair can help you do.

Comment: @oldfred I can't find information on how to do a Summary report, can you specify?

Comment: First link above: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info